# Build the android source codes to get a Complete android.jar with source codes

Tags: java, android, android-source

I tried to download the Android source codes from the following URL:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/fullsdk/sources/android-28/

And tried to compile the content of the downloaded zip file using ANT with javac. However, I got a lot of errors like the module is already in another package and public classes naming error etc.

*I'm currently using java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64*

*Is there is a way to correctly compile the android sources?*

**Note:**

I tried a lot of tutorials on the internet, but they either lead to generating a jar file with stubs instead of sources or fail to explains where the mentioned files are located.

Answer (score 1):

AOSP core parts are usually meant to be built together, since they often refer to one-another.

In the case of making the SDK, you should first get the whole AOSP, and then you can refer to the official guide for making SDK:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt

For reference, I'm quoting the contents of that link here:

```
Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.


Subject: How to build an Android SDK & ADT Eclipse plugin.
Date:    2009/03/27
Updated: 2015/09/09


Table of content:
  0- License
  1- Foreword
  2- Building an SDK for MacOS and Linux
  3- Building an SDK for Windows
  4- Building an ADT plugin for Eclipse
  5- Conclusion



----------
0- License
----------

 Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.



-----------
1- Foreword
-----------

This document explains how to build the Android SDK and the ADT Eclipse plugin.

It is designed for advanced users which are proficient with command-line
operations and know how to setup the pre-required software.

Basically it's not trivial yet when done right it's not that complicated.



--------------------------------------
2- Building an SDK for MacOS and Linux
--------------------------------------

First, setup your development environment and get the Android source code from
git as explained here:

  http://source.android.com/source/download.html

For example for the cupcake branch:

  $ mkdir ~/my-android-git
  $ cd ~/my-android-git
  $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master -g all,-notdefault,tools
  $ repo sync

Then once you have all the source, simply build the SDK using:

  $ cd ~/my-android-git
  $ . build/envsetup.sh
  $ lunch sdk-eng
  $ make sdk

This will take a while, maybe between 20 minutes and several hours depending on
your machine. After a while you'll see this in the output:

  Package SDK: out/host/darwin-x86/sdk/android-sdk_eng.<build-id>_mac-x86.zip

Some options:

- Depending on your machine you can tell 'make' to build more things in
  parallel, e.g. if you have a dual core, use "make -j4 sdk" to build faster.

- You can define "BUILD_NUMBER" to control the build identifier that gets
  incorporated in the resulting archive. The default is to use your username.
  One suggestion is to include the date, e.g.:

  $ export BUILD_NUMBER=${USER}-`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`

  There are certain characters you should avoid in the build number, typically
  everything that might confuse 'make' or your shell. So for example avoid
  punctuation and characters like $ & : / \ < > , and .



------------------------------
3- Building an SDK for Windows
------------------------------

Full Windows SDK builds are now only supported on Linux -- most of the
framework is not designed to be built on Windows so technically the Windows
SDK is build on top of a Linux SDK where a few binaries are replaced. So it
cannot be built on Windows, and it cannot be built on Mac, only on Linux.

I'll repeat this again because it's important:

  To build the Android SDK for Windows, you need to use a *Linux* box.


A- Pre-requisites
-----------------

Before you can even think of building the Android SDK for Windows, you need to
perform the steps from section "2- Building an SDK for MacOS and Linux" above:
setup and build a regular Linux SDK. Once this working, please continue here.

Under Ubuntu, you will need the following extra packages:

$ sudo apt-get install tofrodos

tofrodos adds a unix2dos command


B- Building
-----------

To build, perform the following steps:

$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk-eng
$ make win_sdk

Note that this will build both a Linux SDK then a Windows SDK.
The result is located at
   out/host/windows/sdk/android-sdk_eng.${USER}_windows/


C- Building just the tools
--------------------------------------

You can also build isolated windows tools directly on Linux without building
the full SDK.

To build, perform the following steps:

  $ cd ~/my-android-git
  $ . build/envsetup.sh
  $ lunch sdk-eng
  $ make winsdk-tools

A specific tool can be built using:

  $ make host_cross_adb

Then the binaries are located at
  out/host/windows-x86/bin/adb.exe


-------------------------------------
4- Building an ADT plugin for Eclipse
-------------------------------------

We've simplified the steps here.
It used to be that you'd have to download a specific version of
Eclipse and install it at a special location. That's not needed
anymore.

Instead you just change directories to your git repository and invoke the
build script by giving it a destination directory and an optional build number:

  $ mkdir ~/mysdk
  $ cd ~/my-android-git   # <-- this is where you did your "repo sync"
  $ sdk/eclipse/scripts/build_server.sh ~/mysdk $USER


The first argument is the destination directory. It must be absolute. Do not
give a relative destination directory such as "../mysdk" -- this would make the
Eclipse build fail with a cryptic message:

  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
  Total time: 1 minute 5 seconds
  **** Package in ../mysdk
  Error: Build failed to produce ../mysdk/android-eclipse
  Aborting

The second argument is the build "number". The example used "$USER" but it
really is a free identifier of your choice. It cannot contain spaces nor
periods (dashes are ok.) If the build number is missing, a build timestamp will
be used instead in the filename.

The build should take something like 5-10 minutes.


When the build succeeds, you'll see something like this at the end of the
output:

  ZIP of Update site available at ~/mysdk/android-eclipse-v200903272328.zip
or
  ZIP of Update site available at ~/mysdk/android-eclipse-<buildnumber>.zip

When you load the plugin in Eclipse, its feature and plugin name will look like
"com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_0.9.0.v200903272328-<buildnumber>.jar". The
internal plugin ID is always composed of the package, the build timestamp and
then your own build identifier (a.k.a. the "build number"), if provided. This
means successive builds with the same build identifier are incremental and
Eclipse will know how to update to more recent ones.



-------------
5- Conclusion
-------------

This completes the howto guide on building your own SDK and ADT plugin.
Feedback is welcome on the public Android Open Source forums:
  http://source.android.com/discuss

If you are upgrading from a pre-cupcake to a cupcake or later SDK please read
the accompanying document "howto_use_cupcake_sdk.txt".

-end-
```